# Title Shake from Audio XNA

Tags: c#, audio, xna, visualization

I'm using XNA. I'm wondering if on the menu screen I can make the title picture(PNG) shake like it is vibrating from a boom-box. I have a certain mp3 that will be playing in the background. Do you have any idea as to how I can do this? Thanks so much!

Comment: I was playing around with the GetVisualizationData method, but I wasn't able to figure out how I was going to scale the image according to the sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approaches:

- Just move the title in arbitrary rhythmic fashion in such a way that it seems to fit with the music. Fiddle with it until it looks right. Unfortunately you'll have to re-adjust the animation if you change the song.
- Use the MediaPlayer class to play the song and use its [GetVisualizationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.getvisualizationdata.aspx) method to get frequency and sample data. Move the title as a function of it, somehow. Again, you'll have to figure out a good heuristic yourself. For instance, if you average absolute amplitude over the last X samples, that gives you a measure of the volume, so you can make the animation more or less intense depending on that.

I wouldn't spend too much time on this, players tend to spend their time playing, not admiring the main menu.

Comment: I would use the GetVisualizationData method. If I was to do this though, how would I do it. Could I get an integer from the GetVisualizationData and just scale the image a little?

Comment: @ChanceLeachman Look at the definition of the method I linked to, and to that of VizualizationData. It gives you amplitude and frequency data that you can use to compute whatever animation you want: scaling, translating, color shifts, whatever. If you don't understand what this data represents you should read on digital sound fundamentals.

Comment: I've spent about another hour on this... I just can't find a way to do this. Can you give me code to where I might be able to do this? I want to take the image here:
    

title = new Sprite(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Picture"), new Rectangle(50, 50, 100 + FREQUENCY, 100 + FREQUENCY));

Comment: What is "FREQUENCY" supposed to be? The VizualisationData will give you a collection of floats that represents the normalized power level for a set of frequency bands. Read the documentation and code samples carefully at MSDN, I gave you the link. I don't have time to code it for you and I don't even know exactly what you want.

Comment: you have to find frequency that is most suitable for you... like beating bass. `visData.Frequencies[y]` where y is from 0 to length of array that VisualisationData will give you. as return you will get float from 0.0f to 1.0f